# WPF Binding to a sub-collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a Grid control defined in WPF...

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Further down, I have defined an ItemsControl...

```
 <ItemsControl Name="EntitlementsList" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Entitlements, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Margin="0 10 0 3" AlternationCount="2">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            ...
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:Entitlement}">
                <Grid Margin="0 0 10 0" >
                    <Grid.Style>
                      ...
                    </Grid.Style>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        ...
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 2 0 0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                  Style="{DynamicResource NotesToggleButton}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.GetEntitlementDetails, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
                ...
                </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This displays my Entitlements correctly.

The command for the ToggleButton is defined as...

```
private RelayCommand _getEntitlementDetails;
public RelayCommand GetEntitlementDetails
{
    get
    {
        return _getEntitlementDetails ?? (_getEntitlementDetails = new RelayCommand(x =>
        {
            CurrentEntitlement = x as Entitlement;
        }));
    }
}
```

Then I have another ItemsControl that is collapsed until CurrentEntitlement is set...

```
<ItemsControl Name="ProductList" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="150"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ContextManager.CurrentContext.CurrentEntitlement.ProductList, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  Visibility="{Binding ContextManager.CurrentContext.CurrentEntitlement, 
                                                Converter={StaticResource NullVisibilityConverter}}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
        ...
</ItemsControl>
```

My item source is ProductList inside the Entitlements class...

```
private ObservableCollection<Product> _productList;
public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList
{
    get { return _productList; }
    set
    {
        _productList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

...where all the properties of "Product" raise OnPropertyChanged.

Now, I have been fully expecting my button to execute the command to set the CurrentEntitlement, make my second ItemsControl visible within the grid and display the ProductList, and stepping through the code shows that CurrentEntitlement does get set with a valid instance with items in the ProductList...but I still see nothing on the UI.  I have been searching for a solution for 3 days, and I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I am at my wit's end!

I can't see the issue.  What am I doing wrong here?

Visual Studio 2015 Community, targeting 4.5, running on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finally figuring it out.  There was a binding to some data that was written incorrectly that invalidated the second ItemsControl.